# sqrt: ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, math

I'm facing a problem with "`distance ValueError: math domain error`" when using `sqrt` function in python.

Here is my code:

```
from math import sqrt

def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    x3 = x2-x1
    xFinal = x3^2
    y3 = y2-y1
    yFinal = y3^2
    final = xFinal + yFinal
    d = sqrt(final)
    return d
```

Comment: How about replacing the last seven lines of your code with the following one line? `return sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)` - your code will be clearer because you will be using less variables.

Answer (score 11):

Your issue is that exponentiation in Python is done using `a ** b` and not `a ^ b` (`^` is bitwise XOR) which causes final to be a negative value, which causes a domain error.

Your fixed code:

```
def distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
     return ((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) ** .5 # to the .5th power equals sqrt
```

Comment: if you're trying to improve OP's code, you might as well re-write it to not be entirely horrible. See eumiro's comment.

Answer (score 6):

The power function in Python is `**`, not `^` (which is bit-wise xor).  So use `x3**2` etc.