# Python math domain error on distance formula

Tags: python, math

In my code:

```
class Vector(object):
    @staticmethod
    def distance(vector1, vector2):
        return math.sqrt((vector2[0]-vector1[0])^2+(vector2[1]-vector1[1])^2)
```

Sometimes, seemingly at random, I get a ValueError: math domain error when calling this method. What's the issue? Thanks.

Comment: An excellent argument for testing.

Comment: I think a bigger problem are the values returned when you don't have an exception raised!

Comment: @Patrick Moloney: It appears that your vector world is limited to integers ... the result of trying it on floats may have given you a clue: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'`

Comment: @John as each coordinate represents a pixel on the screen, integers will do just fine

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Beyond "Excellent".  This is the poster-child for testing.  That anyone would have considered this code to "work" at all is a bit alarming.

Comment: @S.Lott: "works" is commonly conflated with "doesn't raise an exception" :-(

Comment: **Duplicate** of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735448/sqrt-valueerror-math-domain-error but don't close this question -- the earlier answers don't mention `math.hypot()`

Comment: @S.Lott The programming language I was used to used ^ for the power operator. I don't find that alarming at all. It's commonly used to represent power in text if superscripts are not available. It was a simple misconception on my part.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Use `**` to raise to a power](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator), i.e.

```
    return math.sqrt((vector2[0]-vector1[0])**2+(vector2[1]-vector1[1])**2)
```

In Python and many other C-derived languages, `^` stands for [bitwise-xor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR), and it could create a negative number, leading to that "math domain error".

BTW, the whole operation can be computed with [the `math.hypot` function](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/math.html#math.hypot).

```
    return math.hypot(vector2[0]-vector1[0], vector2[1]-vector1[1])
```

Comment: `hypot` is preferable for both speed (all operations done in C code) and accuracy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypot).

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is using xor ^ instead of pow **... try replacing that line for:

```
   return math.sqrt((vector2[0]-vector1[0])**2+(vector2[1]-vector1[1])**2)
```